# Integral of $p(x)\operatorname{csch}(x)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I'd like to calculate the following integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^4 \left(\frac 1 {a^2+x^2} +\frac 1 {b^2+x^2}\right)}{\sinh^2(x\pi /c)} \, dx$$

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive constants. Any suggestions? I probably have to use contour integrals, but I'm not sure of which would be the most convenient contour, nor if there's an easy way (I know that the solution has something like the Trigamma function on it).
Thanks a lot! You've been so helpful with my previous questions!

Comment: Today's not my day jaja Now it's correct. If we plot the function, it seems to go to zero when $x\rightarrow 0$

Comment: What is the purpose of the parameters $b$ and $c$? Wouldn't to study $$ I(a) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^4}{\sinh^2(\pi x)(x^2+a^2)}\,dx $$ be just the same problem?

Comment: that's exactly the integral that I have to solve, but the resolution for any integral of the way $p(x)/sinh^{2}(x)$ should be analogous, right?

Comment: @SangchulLee $\sinh x$ is like $e^x$ at $x=+\infty$. Also, at $x=0$ there is no singularity in the integral due to $x^4$.

Comment: @AD., Before the edit, the denominator was $\operatorname{sinh}^2(\pi c/x)$ as you can check from the edit history. It is good that now OP's integral is correct.

Comment: @SangchulLee I see, no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously two of the parameters are redundant, so let us just study:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I(a) &=& \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^4}{\sinh^2(\pi x)}\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)}\\&=&-a^2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2\,dx}{(x^2+a^2)\sinh^2(\pi x)}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2\,dx}{\sinh^2(\pi x)}\\&=&\frac{1}{6\pi}-a^2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2}{\sinh^2(\pi x)}\frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}\\&=&\frac{1}{6\pi}+\frac{a}{2\pi}+a^4\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sinh^2(\pi x)}-\frac{1}{\pi^2 x^2}\right)\frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*}$$
We may recall that:
$$ \frac{\sinh(\pi z)}{\pi z}=\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)\tag{2} $$
so, by considering $-\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\log(\cdot)$ of both sides,
$$ \frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{\pi^2}{\sinh^2(\pi z)} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+iz)^2}+\frac{1}{(n-iz)^2}\right)\tag{3}$$
and now we may compute $(1)$ through $(3)$, since:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{(z^2+a^2)}\left(\frac{1}{(n+iz)^2}+\frac{1}{(n-iz)^2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{a(n+a)^2}.\tag{4}$$
$(4)$ gives that $(1)$ just depends on $\psi'(a)$, the already mentioned trigamma function:
$$ \psi'(a) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}.\tag{5}$$
By $(1),(4)$ and $(5)$ we get:

> $$ I(a)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^4\,dx}{(x^2+a^2)\sinh^2(\pi x)}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{6\pi}+\frac{a}{2\pi}-\frac{a^3}{\pi}\psi'(a+1)}.\tag{6}$$

Comment: Thanks for your proof, Jack! I will go over it and see if all is correct. How do you get equation (4)?

Comment: @Sebasen: probably I got some sign wrong, but I hope the approch is clear. $(4)$ is just a tedious integral than can be computed through partial fraction decomposition and/or the residue theorem.